# Changing the line-height inside a div after ajax call

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set the line-height of words in a div after an ajax call. After I added the code below to my ajax function, the function stopped working. What is wrong with the code below? Thanks.

```
objDiv.style.line-height = '20px';
```

Comment: Should be lineHeight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct property is `lineHeight` not `line-height`

```
objDiv.style.lineHeight = '20px';
```

Comment: I assume it was line-height because it's that in css, and html.

Answer (score 1):

Try camelCase:

```
objDiv.style.lineHeight = '20px';
```